# React start project issue

Tags: reactjs

I have two more React projects It's all in a different folder. From some point on, when I enter npm start in all projects, the same project is executed. I tried to kill every port on the terminal, but it still shows me the same project.
If I create a new project and then start to react app, it also executed other project.
I don't know what happens.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots

Comment: Could you run `cat ./package.json` and post that? Or just copy its contents and add it to your question. Also, you can try to run with `verbose` flag to see exactly what is happening on your start.

Comment: When you start one of the other projects do you see an error that says "port already in use"?

Comment: When I run project 1, project 1 is executed. And if I run project 2 while project 1 is running, I get an error telling me to use another port because it is already in use 3000. So if I enter yes, project 2 will be executed with 3001. But if I don't run project 1 and run project 2, project 1 will be executed. No matter what project I run, project 1 is executed. I'm definitely on the right path and even if I kill all the ports and run them again, Project 1 will be executed. I don't even know where or how to search for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are windows user then you can try using `npx Kill`